# How do you move the cursor to the end of a string in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Let's say I'm editing this line of JavaScript in Vim:

```
var opener = 'As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect';
```

If my cursor is on the `G` in `Gregor`, how do I move it to the `t` in `insect`?

I'm not talking about moving to the end of the *line*. I'm talking about moving to the end of the JavaScript *string* encapsulated in the single quotation marks. (I know I can do it with `/'h`, but I'm wondering if there's a more generic command—maybe something like `%`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move to end of line in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105721/how-to-move-to-end-of-line-in-vim)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105721/how-to-move-to-end-of-line-in-vim

Comment: You've misread the question. I've edited it to emphasize that I'm talking about moving to the end of the _string_, not the end of the _line_.

Comment: Esc, /', enter, i. This will take you to command mode, search for the next ' then take you back to edit mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `vi'<Esc>`, which goes into visual mode with the selection comprising the interior of the current string, and the cursor at the end of the selection — then leaves visual mode.

I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

The *easiest* way would be `t'`, but this would only work if the string ends on the same line and there are no escaped quotes in the string.

The *cleanest* way to achieve this would be as @hobbs already pointed out to use visual mode to select the whole (inside) text object (`vi'<Esc>`). With `o` (before hitting `<Esc>`) you can also toggle the end of this selection.

You can use a mapping for this, something like:

`:noremap [ vi'o<Esc>`

`:noremap ] vi'<Esc>`

And finally there is a plugin (https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) from Tom McDonald that handle exactly your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the easiest way is just `f'`, since hardly can we see another `'` before this tag. It's more convenient even though not like `%` for `(` and `{`.

Answer (score -1):

Use e to the end of Gregor and $ to the end of the line.