# How to jump to the end of the looong line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

All

have file with long data lines, which on screen looks like

```
1    A0    B0    C0    D0    E0    F0
     A1    B1    C1    D1    E1    F1
     A2    B2    C2    D2    E2    F2
2    G0    H0    I0    J0    K0    L0
     G1    H1    I1    J1    K1    L1
     ....
```

due to wrapping.

Cursor located at `A0`. I would like to jump to the end of line #1, 
so cursor shall be at or after `F2`. If I press `End`, I'll be at `F0`,
which is nice to have but not what I would expect.

Is there any good way to jump to the EOL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some looking around, I've got the answer - single `End` key will move you to logical EOL, while hitting second `End` key in succession will move cursor to the physical EOL.

Same for `Home` key - single to logical, twice to physical

Comment: it’s a little sad that your own answer is the only one on topic^^" but it helped me, thx.

Comment: Any setting to look for to assign a custom key? Because when you don't have an end key that's kind of a bummer lol

Comment: If you're annoyed by the default behavior or want to assign custom key head to `File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts` lookup `cursorEnd` (for soft EOL) or `cursorLineEnd` (for physical EOL) and assign whatever.

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker You have to change Keyboard shortcuts. Assign key to 'cursorEnd' function for logical EOL and to 'cursorLineEnd' for physical EOL

Answer (score 2):

In vim: <kbd>$</kbd> in command mode takes you to the end of the line. The pipe symbol (<kbd>|</kbd>) is also handy for getting you to a specific column number; e.g. <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> gets you to column number 30.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to go to the end of a line in the text editor?

Pressing 'End' will take you to the end of the line that the cursor is on (and 'Home' will take you back to the beginning.)

Comment: Lines are wrapped up. Logical eol != Physical eol.

Comment: I've never used vs code so was just giving a general answer, but is there no way to soft wrap?

Comment: One could toggle wrapping on per-file basis, but that makes it all VERY slow. Just to be clear - two lines in that file are ~300K numbers per single line.

Comment: I myself found the answer, please check it

Answer (score 0):

For long data lines VSCode enable **Word Wrap**.
With enabled word wrap:

```
1    A0    B0    C0    D0    E0    F0
     A1    B1    C1    D1    E1    F1
     A2    B2    C2    D2    E2    F2
```

Without word wrap:

```
1    A0 B0 C0 D0 E0 F0 A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2
```

You can toggle this option in *View > Toggle Word Wrap*

So when you disable word wrap, you can use End key as you want (to the end of line).

Comment: Well, i know about that and it is cumbersome and slow - redrawing forth and back etc. It would be nice if there is a function to unwrap a line (single line!) and wrap it back, then I could write small function doing just that (disable redraw->unwrap->go-to-eol->wrap->enable redraw) and assign it to key

Comment: To be clear - two lines in that file are ~300K numbers per single line.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux May be try this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim
It has a lot of original Vim commands, so I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105721/how-do-i-move-to-end-of-line-in-vim commands will perform correct.